# Magento 2.1.5 import error that mess category saving

Tags: magento2, php

**this is what happening with the store i´m building: I have 280k products to import, i´m doing it in with 7 csv files every file contains 40k of data except the last one,**

My problem is the following:

I import the first 40k of data with all the attributes i need, then when the import process is complete i can´t save the categories where the products are assigned.

A thing i want to do is just to create one url for my product bcause when i upload a product for both categories,

`i.e: category-parent,category-parent/category-child` the system creates two url for both categories like this: **category-parent/my-product** and **category-parent/category-child/my-product**, what i want is this: **category-parent/category-child/my-product**

Answer (score 0):

Magento creates a complete path for every category parent, no matter if you associate it to just one, so you can't prevent that without overriding core files, however there is a solution for this:

1. Set "Use canonical Link Meta Tag for categories" to yes:

> When canonical meta tags for categories are enabled, the category page
>   of your store includes a canonical URL to the full category URL:
>   i.e: http://mystore.com/furniture/living-room/microfiber-sofa-sleeper